# TaskDialog with no buttons

Tags: c++, windows-7, messagebox, taskdialog

Is it possible to show the TaskDialog with no buttons? I would like to be able to show just a progress bar (with a message), and then close the TaskDialog window when when my processing is complete (from the Timer event). Right now, I can show a disabled button and then call ButtonClick to close the window, but showing no buttons and having a CloseDialog method would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `TaskDialog()` and `TaskDialogIndirect()` force a default button if you do not specify any buttons, but you do have control over what kind of buttons are used, so I would place an Abort button in the dialog to cancel whatever operation you are displaying status of.  Or maybe a Hide button if the user does not want to see the progress anymore without stopping the operation that is in progress.

You have to use `TaskDialogIndirect()` in order to activate the progress bar feature. You can also use its callback feature to obtain the `HWND` of the dialog so you can close it programmably when needed.

Otherwise, don't use the TaskDialog API. Just create your own window with your own UI, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 3):

Derive your own class from CTaskDialog

```
class CTaskDlg : public CTaskDialog
{
in CTaskDlg.h declare:
    public:
        void CloseTaskDlg(void);
protected:
    HWND m_TaskDlgHwnd;
    virtual HRESULT OnInit();
};
```

in CTaskDialog.cpp:

```
void CTaskDlg::CloseTaskDlg(void)
{
    ::SendMessage(m_TaskDlgHwnd, TDM_CLICK_BUTTON, static_cast<WPARAM>(TDCBF_OK_BUTTON), 0);
}

HRESULT CTaskDlg::OnInit()
{
    m_TaskDlgHwnd = ::GetActiveWindow();
    return S_OK;
}

CTaskDlg dlg;
dlg.CloseTaskDlg();
```